# R-code to do a scatter plot matrix

Tags: r

I have the following set of data:

```
pcb138  pcb180  pcb52   pcb118  pcb

1,46    ,738    ,532    ,72 19,9959
,64 ,664    ,03 ,236    6,0996
3,29    1,15    ,134    1,54    24,9655
3,94    1,33    ,466    1,94    37,4436
3,18    2,14    ,243    1,47    30,183
2,43    1,3 ,137    1,31    20,8036
3,94    3,49    ,208    ,876    41,3818
3,38    1,04    ,477    2,46    29,478
2,21    ,966    ,457    1,14    24,2387
2,49    1,59    ,298    1,18    26,3198
,86 ,395    ,02 ,406    8,591
3,38    1,85    ,539    1,5 36,4229
7,39    4,42    ,707    3,55    66,4108
2,74    ,595    ,893    1,98    30,5757
2,58    1,78    ,112    1,52    25,4771
7,28    3,49    1,44    4   68,5567
2,29    2,1 ,124    ,981    23,1381
5,35    5,37    ,154    ,737    43,0451
4,62    2,69    ,319    1,49    39,53
3,54    1,14    ,536    1,89    36,5013
1,98    1,04    ,718    ,889    26,5255
2,01    1,04    ,173    1,5 22,137
2,22    ,897    ,228    1,07    19,1992
3,5 2,33    ,456    1,52    32,9518
,86 ,474    ,152    ,393    9,0893
4,92    3,65    ,181    1,79    42,0037
2,76    ,868    1,78    2,14    48,7727
5,18    3,61    ,843    2,39    55,894
2,6 1,24    ,482    1,6 31,8021
4,95    2,74    1,29    2,35    60,1485
10,8    8,82    ,067    3,55    97,2793
2,02    1,39    ,311    1,31    18,3945
3,24    2,6 ,117    1,74    27,5003
8,22    7,07    ,531    2,56    79,0347
9,5 9,47    ,752    2,42    97,8119
4,88    2,69    ,304    2,6 44,887
5,75    3,1 ,595    1,85    58,2125
5,48    5,46    ,352    1,54    57,4186
8,08    3,37    ,065    3,58    57,4938
3,29    2,37    ,34 1,35    33,5817
3,73    1,02    5,86    3,89    115,7361
1,36    ,624    ,269    ,508    14,8479
9,92    2,81    1,26    4,77    91,6305
8,65    6,21    ,428    3,68    92,1625
4,56    1,15    ,307    2,71    37,0122
8,78    4,69    ,892    3,85    87,6535
13,1    7,63    ,981    4,81    111,3631
5,99    3,06    ,062    2,64    47,9596
3,91    2,48    ,17 3,18    38,0747
6,51    1,47    7,75    5,45    122,796
11,3    4,1 1,62    6,29    113,1166
8,12    3,99    ,867    3,49    79,2042
11,5    9,33    ,707    3,36    98,3269
3,99    2,1 ,328    1,41    33,0017
7,88    2,29    ,667    5,65    64,2417
13  5,04    2,13    6,9 119,3755
9,05    5,08    ,497    3,9 80,6768
21  19  ,645    3,66    171,4136
12,2    17,6    ,188    4,09    132,867
8,63    3,11    1,78    6,09    91,7974
4,39    1,11    ,232    3,35    32,6213
5,95    3,63    ,953    2,91    59,5369
19,7    10,6    4,03    8,59    200,5094
7,6 3,73    ,351    5   65,3966
18,1    9,87    2,75    8,19    198,5225
13,1    4,49    ,538    6,86    89,3715
25,2    13  1,42    13  210,3284
12,3    3,75    9,06    18,9    246,6618
32,3    31,5    1,8 8,49    318,7461
```

How can I draw a scatter plot matrix of it in R? Here, comma means a decimal point.

Comment: I was unable to run that command. 

    tieto<-read.csv2("file:///home/jaakko/Downloads/pcb.dat",header=T)

pairs(~pcb138,data=tieto,
   main="Simple Scatterplot Matrix")

  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'pcb138' not found

Comment: The format of the data in your question seems to be variable. For example, there are five column labels, but six entries in the first row. The column labels should also be separated by columns. Fixing the CSV file will help ```read.csv()```. Note that you should not use ```read.csv2()``` as that is intended for semi-colon separated files.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the little `r` tag under your question you will see a [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) called info. It's unclear how much experience you have using R, but you may find it useful to have a browse of some of the online documentation listed on that page. It is always best to show [**what you have tried already**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @orizon the comma is not a delimter in this place, so there are only 5 entries in the first row. @Student, I suggest you use `read.delim("file:///home/jaakko/Downloads/pcb.dat",header=T , dec = "," , sep = "\t")` to get your data in. The '"\t"' means your data is seperated by tabs Edit: I found that `sep=""` works best - you have variable length whitespace seperating values. Also if you want to refer to columns in the global environment (not recommended) use `attach( tieto )` first.

Comment: @Momo these are not csv values. The comma represents the decimal point.

Comment: @DWin there is nothing wrong with the data (aside from it's untidy as posted) and I never suggested that comma should be a delimiter? (see my comment on Apr 15 at 10:59). Comma is the decimal point and white space is the delimiter. This works just fine on my system using `read.delim`, i.e. `read.delim( text = "paste here" , dec = "," , sep = "" , h = TRUE )`. Perhaps it is confusing that leading zeroes are not printed in the output above?

Comment: It was Student that suggested that this be read in with `read.csv2` which I thought implied that he knew it to be separated with something other than whitespace. As it turned out `read.table` with dec="," and header=TRUE did work fine (with no `sep` argument other than the default.)

Answer (score 2):

The opportunities are vast:

- Basic scatterplot matrices are provided by the base function `pairs`
- An augmented version of these is provided by `scatterplot.matrix` in
  the `car` package
- You can also use `splom` from the `lattice` package
- Then there's the still kind of experimental `ggpairs` from the
  `GGally` package, based on ggplot2
- And also, a very young package for this is `gpairs`, containing a
  function of the same name

I like the implementation in the `car` package best, but each has its merits, with the last two offering the most features but also being the least mature.